# Play drums with a MIDI keyboard

Tags: keyboard, midi

How could I use my Novation Ultranova to play various types of drums with the keyboard ?
(it does not contain any drum sound)

Do I need additional hardware or simply a software with samples?

How to play a given sample each time I press a key on the Ultranova ? (connected to the PC via an USB cable)

Answer (score 4):

Since the Ultranova has MIDI out (both using traditional 5 pin DIN MIDI connections, and over USB) you just need some software on your PC that translates MIDI notes into drum sounds.

Any drum software that claims to support "MIDI in" will do this.

That includes all the mainstream DAWs - Cubase, Ableton Live, etc. and many dedicated drum programs, some of which are free.